# Comparison method violates its general contract, how to make it transitive?

Tags: java, android, comparator

I dont see how it is **not transitive**, please someone suggest me the right way.
if both values are `null`

I return 0, the two other statements are pretty obvious.

Why i got `IllegalArgumentException` with:
**Comparison method violates its general contract**

My compare method: (I compare doubles)

```
@Override
public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs, HashMap<String, String> rhs) {

    double dist1 = 0;
    double dist2 = 0;

    int compInt1 = 0;
    int compInt2 = 0;

    if (lhs.get("dist") != null && rhs.get("dist") != null && !lhs.get("dist").equals("") && !rhs.get("dist").equals("")) {

        dist1 = Double.parseDouble(lhs.get("dist").substring(0, lhs.get("dist").length() - 3));
        dist2 = Double.parseDouble(rhs.get("dist").substring(0, rhs.get("dist").length() - 3));

        dist1 = dist1 * 100;
        dist2 = dist2 * 100;

        compInt1 = (int) dist1;
        compInt2 = (int) dist2;

    }

    if (compInt1 < compInt2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (compInt1 >= compInt2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: `if both values are null

I return 0` no you don't

Answer (score 3):

Look at this code:

```
if (compInt1 < compInt2) {
    return -1;
} else if (compInt1 >= compInt2) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

How do you expect that ever to return 0? What values of `compInt1` and `compInt2` would make *both* `if` conditions fail?

This violates symmetry too - it means that `compare(x, y)` and `compare(y, x)` can both return 1...

Assuming you're really just trying to compare `compInt1` and `compInt2` in the obvious way at this point, just replace the whole block with:

```
// As of Java 7...
return Integer.compare(compInt1, compInt2);
```

If you're using Java 6 (or earlier) you could use:

```
return Integer.valueOf(compInt1).compareTo(compInt2);
```

That's a *little* inefficient, but it's at least worth using to start with, just to get everything working.

Additionally, I'd *strongly* recommend extracting the `lhs.get("dist")` and `rhs.get("dist")` expressions from your first part - it's *horribly* repetitive at the moment. And just declare `dist1` and `dist2` within the block - they're not used elsewhere.

Comment: I does not except it, i read on stack that this is neceserry to resolve this issue, in fact it does not resolved.

Comment: @Adam: which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: I have no idea what you mean by your first comment, by the way.

Comment: It is an error message, by the way i tryed with:
return Integer.valueOf(compInt1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(compInt2));

Does not resolved.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: What is the *exact* error message. I'm sure it isn't just "does not resolved" which isn't even valid English.

Answer (score 0):

The condition  `else if (compInt1 >= compInt2)` is ambiguous as it would return a value of 1 even if both values are equal. Replace your comparison logic of ints as follows :

```
 return compInt1  - compInt2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Transitivity defines as :

```
compare(a, b) == -compare(b, a)
```

Which implies `compare(a, a) == -compare(a, a) == 0`

Now, considering your code,

```
compare(a, a) == 1
```